# Hard Hat Error HH100: Network mainnet doesn't exist. How do I configure my file so that it can find the main/test net?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, solidity, hardhat

[image: mainnet doesn't exist]

How do I connect to the mainnet? It keeps saying it doesn't exist, same with other test networks.

I am brand new to hard hat and would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Where is `hardhat.config.js` compared to the directory you are using in your terminal?